Framer Motion - Split Text Animation Tailwind Gradient Color
I'm working a bit with Framer Motion and I have the following problem:
<div className="space-y-3">
  <div>
    <H1 className="text-nowrap text-center md:text-start">
      {text.split("").map((letter, index) => (
        <motion.span
          className="bg-gradient-to-r from-red-600 to-yellow-300 bg-clip-text text-transparent"
          key={index}
          initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
          animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
          transition={{
            duration: 3,
            repeat: Infinity,
            delay: index * 0.1,
          }}
        >
          {letter}
        </motion.span>
      ))}
      
    </H1>
  </div>
</div>

I know that the Text is splitted and that is the reason why the gradient effect is shown on each letter and not over the whole text.
My problem is: I don't know how to solve it...
Unfortunaltey I don't find any solution by looking into the docs from Framer Motion and maybe anybody can give me the nudge in the right direction?


HI @Kiezgold I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to place the gradient effect over the entire text or on each letter of the text?

Hi @praizjosh I'm trying to place the gradient effect over the whole text. At the moment the effect is on each letter individually, which of course doesn't look good because the effect starts new with each letter.

Can you share an image of what it currently looks like?

I add an example in the original post. Thank you

Hey, that's because you wrapped your text inside the map function which splits your text into single letters. Try removing text.split("").map((letter, index) => part from your code.

As you've noticed, the text has been splitted into single letters, and that's why the gradient effect was applied on each letter.
So, just try by unwrapping your text from text.split("").map((letter, index) => method.
<div className="space-y-3">
  <div>
    <H1 className="text-nowrap text-center md:text-start">
      <motion.span
        className="bg-gradient-to-r from-red-600 to-yellow-300 bg-clip-text text-transparent"
        key={index}
        initial={{ opacity: 1 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 0 }}
        transition={{
          duration: 3,
          repeat: Infinity,
          delay: index * 0.1,
        }}
      >
        {text}
      </motion.span>
      
    </H1>
  </div>
</div>

